# Overflow: hidden does not apply in Firefox 5 when set via JavaScript

Tags: css, firefox

**This is confirmed to be a bug in Firefox and you can learn more about it at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686247**

I am setting `overflow` to `hidden` via jQuery but it does not get applied in Firefox 5 while in other browsers it does get applied well. Please test this jsfiddle to see the problem yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/f4HJd/ And here is an image of how it looks in Firefox 5: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zfy.png and an image of that in Chrome to compare: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKVPB.png What is wrong with `overflow` in FF5?

**EDIT:**

After some tests I found out that the `overflow` property does get applied to elements that have been added dynamically via JavaScript. So, that means we can workaround the bug by replacing the element in question with its copy and applying `overflow: hidden` to it as follows in jQuery:

```
$('textarea').replaceWith($('textarea').clone().css('overflow', 'hidden'));
```

Just as a side note, we could even avoid replacing the element when possible like so:

```
// for all browsers
$('textarea').css('overflow', 'hidden');
// for FF only
if ($.browser.mozilla) $('textarea').replaceWith($('textarea').clone());
```

**EDIT 2:**

As further tests showed, `overflow: hidden` also get applied well when the `position` property is set to `absolute` or when the `display` property is set to either `block` or `inline-block`, via CSS statically or via JavaScript. So, something like this can easily help out:

```
$('textarea').css({ display: 'inline-block', overflow: 'hidden' });
```

**EDIT 3:**

The problem only appear to be regarding textarea elements. I tested it on DIV elements and the content get clipped well. So, I suspect it is because textarea elements are inline and the overflow property is meant to work for block-level elements.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but your code works fine when you select "no wrap" in the script options: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4HJd/1/).

Comment: @lonesomeday, indeed! Now I'm also wondering how come?

Comment: That's crazy! I think it's an incompatibility between jsfiddle and firefox, did you try it in FF4 and lower?

Comment: @Milimetric, as Chris explained, this is some nasty FF bug but I don't know if it exists in any other versions.

Comment: Looks like it's there in FF6 as well, Chris' work-around should be good though, except for possible FOUC.

Comment: Anybody knows if this bug has been reported? Just interesting how come it exists in the latest versions of Firefox!

Comment: Bug reported. For more info, please refer to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Firefox. The call from jQuery to set overflow equal to hidden doens't seem to work in Firefox unless you set the textarea's css overflow to a value in your css or style attribute first, then tell jQuery to set overflow to hidden.

```
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
}

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Although, I am curious why you don't just create a css class for that textarea, instead of relying on javascript to hide it's scrollbars in the first place.

Comment: Well, I need such functionality in a jQuery plugin I am writing so I was planning to set it via jQuery, but if that's a bug in FF itself than I will certainly have to set in CSS. Thanks for your help!