# don't allow iframe to scroll until parent has reached the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a iframe in it, the iframe has enough content that it always has to have a scroll bar.

How can i only allow the iframe to start scrolling when the parent page is at the bottom?

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: sure - http://jsfiddle.net/yA8mR/

Comment: referring to this http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/yA8mR/1/ one can you tell what behavior you actually want to add in the page

Comment: The behaviour is in the title. Say you hovered over the iframe and scrolled to the bottom of the main page, he doesn't want the iframe to start scrolling until you reach the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
 var scrollHeight;

 $('body').animate({scrollTop: 1200},10,function()
 {
    scrollHeight=$(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').scrollTop(0)
 })

$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({

'overflow-y':'hidden'
})

$('iframe').contents().find('body').append($('body').clone())

$('iframe').contents().find('body iframe').css('background','lightblue')

$('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background','lightgreen').find('h3').text("Cloned")

//note that horizontal bar inside iframe belongs to cloned body not iframe

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st >=scrollHeight){

      $('iframe').contents().find('body').css({

  'overflow-y':'auto'
  })    
    }
});
})

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Page content goes here</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<iframe  style=" border: 2px red solid" height="300px" width="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Worked In** chrome 31.0.1650.57 m, opera 16.0.1196.73, safari 5.1.7

**Not Worked In**
firefox 25.0.1 [reason can be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7371863/1642219)

IE9 `as expected lol :)`

**EDIT AFTER ISSUE MENTIONED COMMENTS**

*i haven't tested this but hope it will work*

```
<iframe name="frame" src="xyz.php" style=" border: 2px red solid" height="300px" width="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
  var scrollHeight;
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: 1200},10,function()
  {
   scrollHeight=$(window).scrollTop();
   $('body').scrollTop(0)
  })

 var doc=window.frames[ "frame" ].document  //use iframe's name

 $(doc).ready(function(){
  $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow','hidden')

 });



 $(window).scroll(function(){
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();

 if(st >=scrollHeight){

  $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow','auto')
  }
});
})
```

Comment: the fiddle works but on my page, when i scroll to the bottom the iframe scroll bar isn't showing

Comment: @charlie i have edited the answer, i hope this will work. Also if iframe is loading page from another domain it will not work because you can't access the contents of iframe in that case due to security measures used in browsers

Comment: that works fine but its changing the src of my iframe

Comment: its changing from this line $('iframe').contents().find('body').append($('body').clone())
 i want it to keep the SRC i have in the HTML

Comment: @charlie code in the answer is just for demonstration purpose you can remove the three lines `above the comment`. Also please consider my last comment about external domains

Comment: i have removed that code and it just leaves the scroll bar in the iframe before i have hit the bottom of the parent page. I am not using an external domain - that was just an example. i am using a local PHP page

Comment: you have to perform the iframe contents accessing stuff and making overflow hidden when the `documnent` of iframe is ready/loaded just like we do for the parent window http://stackoverflow.com/a/19423398/1642219 . Also **note** that i have removed the `src` attribute of iframe in the answer (*in case you have used the exact code*)

Comment: sorry - I'm not great with JS. i don't suppose you can do an example please :)

Comment: @charlie have a look at the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the iframe scrolling attribute:

```
$('iframe').attr('scrolling','no');
```

Then use `scroll()` function to detect the bottom scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
        $('iframe').attr('scrolling','yes');    
    }
});
```

---

Thanks @putvande for pointing that out, MDN says works **HTML4 only** ([MDN `<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)) but I can still see it properly working on my chrome browser. Also `overflow:hidden` for `<iframe>` is not yet fully supported by all modern browsers.

I think the safest way is setting both CSS `'overflow'` and `scrolling=""` attribute.

```
$('iframe').attr('scrolling','no').css({'overflow':'hidden'});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
       $('iframe').attr('scrolling','yes').css({'overflow':'auto'});   
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `scrolling` is HTML4 only (so won't work in HMTL5). You could just set `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: auto`;